# Nginx upstream block nondefault port

Tags: nginx, ssl, load-balancing, https

experts.

I am trying to configure nginx/1.10.0 for upstream to 2 https web servers on non standart port with ssl termination.

Here is my current website setup in sites-available/

```
upstream backend {
        ip_hash;
        server 172.31.16.1:8444;
        server 172.31.16.2:8444;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen 8444 ssl;
        ssl on;
        server_name backend_1;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;

#--------ssl certificates for fronend------------#
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginxSvr.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginxSvr.key;
        ssl_verify_client off;

        location / {
        proxy_pass https://172.31.16.1;
#       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/IPSUMCUICA.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/IPSUMCUICA.key;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        }
```

It works without using upstream section. 
        But when I change proxy_pass to *proxy_pass  https://backend;* I got an error 404, and https://backend:8444 in browser.

Apparently it tried to resolve this name and failed, probably after some error but error log is empty in this case.
All suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: If you change `proxy_pass https://172.31.16.1` to `proxy_pass https://172.31.16.1:8444` what happens?

Comment: BTW (not connected to your problem), you should remove `ssl on`.

Comment: What does the log show when you enable more detailed logging with `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;` directive?

Comment: If I change proxy_pass to https://172.31.16.1:8444  it works(with correct /url accessed ofc). If I try to put proxy_pass https://backend; it goes to default 80 port. If I put https://backend$server_port; or backend$server_port$request_uri; and in backend section strip the port 
to server 172.31.16.1; -  I receive 502 Bad Gateway and  *2 no resolver defined to resolve backend8444 in log.

Comment: *If I try to put proxy_pass backend;* - are you putting `proxy_pass backend;` or `http://backend`?

Comment: All starting with https://

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I found the solution. 
I have added  proxy_set_header Host $http_host; in location directive. Now initial config works.

```
upstream backend {
        ip_hash;
        server 172.31.16.1:8444;
        server 172.31.16.2:8444; } 
server {
            listen 8444 ssl;
            server_name backend_1;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
            ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginxSvr.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginxSvr.key;
    ssl_verify_client off;

    location / {
    proxy_pass https://backend;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
}
```